# Faster way of checking if dialog has closed?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm automating an application (pywinauto ver 0.6.2) in which I:

- search for a record
- open a dialog
- make changes
- click an OK button
- wait for the dialog to close
- when closed, search for the next record, repeat

In the 'wait for the dialog to close' step I am using:

```
dlg.wait_not("visible", timeout=60)
```

This works most of the time, but sometimes it not only doesn't detect that the dialog has closed, but it also doesn't appear to do anything at the 60 second mark.

Is there a better way to detect the close of a window?

Comment: How often is it reproduced? Is the window really closed but `wait_not` still running?

Comment: I don't have any firm stats yet, but I can try collecting them. Yesterday, I ran 10 transactions and it didn't detect the dialog closing on the 7th - the dialog was closed, but the code sat as though it was waiting. Then I quit the app, reran it against another 11 transactions and it ran without issue. It's difficult to predict when it will happen.

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. Which backend do you use? `"win32"` or `"uia"`?

Comment: This code was written for version 0.5.4 - I only recently upgraded to 0.6.2 (note: I saw the same issue with 0.5.4; to get around it I wrote an ugly for loop that tested and caught exceptions). If I'm not specifying the backend, is it defaulting to win32?

Comment: Yes, `"win32"` is a default backend. I had plans to re-write `wait/wait_not` methods that will fix a couple of other problems and inconsistencies like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43225080/3648361). But I'm too busy for some period ahead (pywinauto is a hobby project for now). Probably summer update (0.6.3 or 0.6.4) will contain the fix. If you have a time to dig into this, you're always welcome to make a pull request. ;) And thanks for reporting this!

Comment: [One of the first steps](https://github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/pywinauto/commit/79d4e64cb9aed1d1fb76ae23ad13bfe88a08ce3e) if it will help.

Comment: Do you mean wrapping `dlg.wait('visible', timeout=1)` in a for loop of some  kind?

Comment: Nope. Nevermind, it's internal structure of the method I don't like. I'll try to find time to re-work it.

Comment: The issue is fixed in [this branch](https://github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/pywinauto/tree/thunder-rt6). We plan to release it in May.

Answer (score 1):

The bug with timings is fixed in pywinauto 0.6.3. Please update it with `pip install -U pywinauto`. Method `wait_not` is also affected.